# Setting the width of quoted paragraph narrower than the main texts

Tags: formatting, packages, quotation

I use the dirtytalk package, with UK glyphs.
The current settings produce the following outputs, in which the width of the main body and the quotes are the same. What I want to do is to set the width of paragraph for quoted texts narrower than the main body by default every time I quote in the document. How can I do this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[
    left = `,% 
    right = ',% 
    leftsub = ``,% 
    rightsub = '' %
]{dirtytalk}

\begin{document}

I use the dirtytalk package, with UK glyphs. What I want to do is to set the width of paragraph for quoted texts narrower than the main body by default every time I quote in the document. How can I do this? The current settings produce the following outputs.

\say{All the world’s a stage, and all the men and women merely players. They have their exits and their entrances; And one man in his time plays many parts.}  (Shakespeare, As You Like It, Act 2, Scene 7)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the built-in LaTeX quote environment to the `\say` command if the current level is 1:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[
    left = `,% 
    right = ',% 
    leftsub = ``,% 
    rightsub = '' %
]{dirtytalk}

\makeatletter
% definition copied from dirtytalk.sty
\renewcommand{\say}[1]%
  {%
    \addtocounter{dirtytalk@qdepth}{1}%
    % added the line below
    \ifnum\thedirtytalk@qdepth=1\begin{quote}\fi%
    \dirtytalk@lsymb%
    #1%
    \dirtytalk@rsymb%
    % close the environment
    \ifnum\thedirtytalk@qdepth=1\end{quote}\fi%
    \addtocounter{dirtytalk@qdepth}{-1}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

I use the dirtytalk package, with UK glyphs. What I want to do is to set the width of paragraph for quoted texts narrower than the main body by default every time I quote in the document. How can I do this? The current settings produce the following outputs.

\say{All the world’s a stage, and all the men and women merely players. They have their \say{exits} and their \say{entrances}; And one man in his time plays many parts.}  (Shakespeare, As You Like It, Act 2, Scene 7)

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit: added a version with an optional argument to put the source of the quote aligned with the quote itself, to be used as `\say[author]{quote}`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[
    left = `,% 
    right = ',% 
    leftsub = ``,% 
    rightsub = '' %
]{dirtytalk}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\say}[2][]%
  {%
    \addtocounter{dirtytalk@qdepth}{1}%
    \ifnum\thedirtytalk@qdepth=1\begin{quote}\fi%
    \dirtytalk@lsymb%
    #2%
    \dirtytalk@rsymb%
    \ifnum\thedirtytalk@qdepth=1\end{quote}\fi%
    \addtocounter{dirtytalk@qdepth}{-1}%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax\else\vskip-1em\hspace{\leftmargin}(#1)\vskip1em\fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

I use the dirtytalk package, with UK glyphs. What I want to do is to set the width of paragraph for quoted texts narrower than the main body by default every time I quote in the document. How can I do this? The current settings produce the following outputs.

\say[Shakespeare, As You Like It, Act 2, Scene 7]{All the world’s a stage, and all the men and women merely players. They have their \say{exits} and their \say{entrances}; And one man in his time plays many parts.}

The next paragraph starts with an indent on the first line, as paragraphs do by default, and the second line starts at the edge of the page content which is rather far from the edge of the page itself in regular \LaTeX\ classes.

\say{This quote has no author}

The next paragraph starts with an indent on the first line again.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you think this is too complicated then you can also use the first definition and add `\vskip-1em\hspace{\leftmargin}(Shakespeare etc.)\vskip1em` manually.

Comment: Thank you @Marijn for the detailed guidance. Since I \cite the author using hyperref package, I decided to go for the first example of yours with `\vskip-1em\hspace{\leftmargin}(Shakespeare etc.)\vskip1em`.

I may ask, in the command, is it also possible to quote the main texts in Italics? I currently use \textit manually.

Comment: @yufiP for italics you can put `\itshape%` in the definition on the line above `#2` (so the result is `\dirtytalk@lsymb%` new line `\itshape%` new line `#2%`).

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the hands-on advice :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the `quoting` package, which defines commands for customising the quote and quotation environments, and is indented on both sides by default:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{quoting}

\begin{document}

I use the \emph{dirtytalk} package, with UK glyphs. What I want to do is to set the width of paragraph for quoted texts narrower than the main body by default every time I quote in the document. How can I do this? The current settings produce the following outputs.

\begin{quoting}[begintext=‘, vskip= 0.4ex, indentfirst=false]
All the world’s a stage, and all the men and women merely players. They have their exits and their entrances; And one man in his time plays many parts.’

\raggedleft(Shakespeare, \emph{As You Like It}, Act 2, Scene 7)
\end{quoting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Good to know about the quoting package :) I decided to follow Marijn's answer this time to set everything in one go in the preamble.